# Moved folder causing broken shortcuts

Tags: windows, windows-10, shortcuts

I purchased a new Windows 10 computer and on my old computer i kept most of my files within a master folder called "MyMainFolder". Moving this folder from the old computer to the new computer has caused issues as the path names are no longer the same and as such all the shortcuts are now broken. A *LOT* of shortcuts are broken.

The old path:
C:\Users\RestrictedUserAccount\Desktop\MyMainFolder

The new path:
D:\MyMainFolder

99.9% of all my broken shortcuts could be fixed if there was an automated way to go through all shortcuts and change the beginning of the path name to changing the drive letter from "c" to "d" and then dropping everything up to "MyMainFolder". Does anyone know a way to fix this with a .bat file or another solution? I have been fixing them manually by opening the shortcut and changing the drive letter and dropping everything up to "MyMainFolder" but im going to be at it for months if i have to fix them all myself.

Comment: untested: [ShortcutsSearchAndReplace](http://jacquelin.potier.free.fr/ShortcutsSearchAndReplace/) or portable version [here](https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/shortcuts-search-and-replace-portable)

Comment: And just like that my problem has been fixed. You have no idea how much you just helped me with basically a single sentence. Thank you SOOO much. I also plan on giving them a donation as well- they more than earned it.

Comment: Great, happy to help! I just posted it as an answer, please mark it as accepted so others can see what worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but [ShortcutsSearchAndReplace](http://jacquelin.potier.free.fr/ShortcutsSearchAndReplace/) should do what you need. There is a PortableApps version [here](https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/shortcuts-search-and-replace-portable) as well.

From the website:

> Shortcuts Search And Replace allows to do easy operations on shortcuts
>   :
>
> -  Search for shortcuts target path, working directory, arguments, and icon location content
>
> -  Replace multiple shortcuts target path, working directory, arguments, and icon location content (useful when moving portable
>   applications to another drive or another folder)
>
> -  Search dead links, to resolve or delete them (multiple resolves/delete in single click)